# How to import a DLL to MSScriptControl.ScriptControl

Tags: msscriptcontrol

I have a query on the MS Script Control, I have an VB6 Program that uses the MSScript control to allow users to write Macros inside the application.

My question is how to import a DLL to object of type MSScriptControl.ScriptControl.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean load a scriptControl object?

in vbscript:

```
set x = createobject("msscriptcontrol.scriptcontrol")
x.language = "vbscript"
x.executestatement "a = 12"
```

in vb6:

```
Public Sub class_initialize()
Set Script = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
Script.Language = "VBScript"
Script.Reset
Script.ExecuteStatement "abc = 123"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to declare a variable of type X.  X is an class exist on a DLL. So I need to import the DLL to the Script object.